# JavaScript Unsigned 64 bit ints - BigInt or JS-CUint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, uint64

I need to work with unsigned 64 bit integers in my current project.  Given that Javascript can natively handle numbers no bigger than 2^53 - 1, I have looked around at the alternatives available for handling 64 bit `uints` and found two

- [BigInt](https://github.com/Evgenus/BigInt)
- [JS-CUInt](https://github.com/pierrec/js-cuint)

Both libraries come with an excellent range of functions to operate on large integers.  A cursory reading of JS-CUInt suggests that it has everything I require, including bit arithmetic operators, `toString`, `fromString` etc.

However, it bothers me that neither project has been active of late and at least one of them has dead links.  Is this because native support for 64 bit `units` is now so good that add-ins are not required?  My search for terms such as "Chrome unsigened 64 bit int" etc have not turned up anything useful.

Comment: I think this is too subjective/opinion-based for SO's format. AFAIK there is no native 64-bit int support in JavaScript engines presently. There's a [Stage 3](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) proposal for [`BigInt`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint), which is arbitrary precision, not 64-bit.

Comment: Re not much activity: The problem domain is fairly constrained, it could just be that those libs are mature and do what they need to do.